# Find stored procedure names from database with only SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Find stored procedure names from database with only `SELECT` statements (procedures with update, insert should not be returned in that list).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Note that if a `PROCEDURE` uses obfuscation techniques like `EXEC 'SEL' + 'ECT * FROM'` then that won't work.

Comment: A better idea is to import your database into an SSDT project and then use Visual Studio to go through it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an odd request, but you can leverage `sys.sql_module`

```
SELECT [schema_name] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) 
      ,[object_name] = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) 
      ,definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
Where charindex('UPDATE ',definition)
     +charindex('DELETE ',definition)
     +charindex('INSERT ',definition)  
     =0
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to parse the procedure SQL yourself is a recipe for disaster. What happens if one of your procedures has any of the following?

```
SELECT * FROM [UpdateTable]

-- We don't want to update

UPDATE @MyTableVariable...
```

**The definitive way to do this is to use [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).**

```sql
select schema_name = s.name, p.name
from sys.procedures p
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = p.schema_id
where not exists (select 1
    from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(s.name + '.' + p.name, 'OBJECT') r
    where r.is_updated = 1
);
```

Note that this also takes into account any type of DML, such as `INSERT` `MERGE` or `DELETE`.

Interestingly enough, it also ignores modifications to table variables and temp tables.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db37a7b7167cdb8908aae11cb0dd88ea)